# SharePoint 2013 SOAP - Submit File Method

Tags: sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to submit a file through SharePoint using the SOAP client method (provided through WSDL).

```
SubmitFileResponse response = await client.SubmitFileAsync(content, property, filingLocation.Location, "", _authenticator.Credential.UserName);
```

The response body is then

```
"<ResultCode>InvalidArgument</ResultCode>"
```

The method signature (sans return) is

```
SubmitFileAsync(byte[] fileToSubmit, GimmalAPI.Gimmal.RecordsRepositoryProperty[] properties, string recordRouting, string sourceUrl, string userName)
```

The only parameters I am confused on are recordRouting and sourceUrl. If someone could help me out on understanding what these should be, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

So I have found documentation that has helped me figure this out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313141(v=office.12).aspx

This is the SOAP documentation, and I have found that recordRouting should be the SharePoint document type, while sourceUrl should be the url of the file (as expected).